Writing Flink checkpoints to S3
I have a Flink job for which i need to write checkpoints on S3.
This is my configuration:
config = Configuration()


    config.set_string("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
    config.set_string("fs.s3a.access.key", os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
    config.set_string("fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
    config.set_string("fs.s3a.session.token", os.environ.get("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"))

    stream_exec_env.get_config().set_global_job_parameters(config.to_dict())

    stream_exec_env.enable_checkpointing(checkpoint_interval_ms)

    stream_exec_env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpoint_timeout(checkpoint_timeout_ms)
stream_exec_env.get_checkpoint_config().set_max_concurrent_checkpoints(max_concurrent_checkpoints)
    stream_exec_env.get_checkpoint_config().set_min_pause_between_checkpoints(min_pause_between_checkpoints_ms)

    stream_exec_env.get_checkpoint_config().enable_externalized_checkpoints(
        ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION
    )

    checkpoint_location = "s3a://checkpoints"
    rocks_db_backend = RocksDBStateBackend(checkpoint_location, True)
    stream_exec_env.set_state_backend(rocks_db_backend)

and i also have flink_properties like this:
      execution.checkpointing.storage: 'filesystem'
      execution.checkpointing.dir: 's3a://checkpoints'
      execution.checkpointing.incremental: true
      execution.checkpointing.interval: '3 min'
      execution.checkpointing.mode: 'EXACTLY_ONCE'
      execution.checkpointing.timeout: '10 min'
      execution.checkpointing.min-pause: '1 min'
      execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 1
      execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention: 'RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION'
#      execution.checkpointing.num-retained: 3 # it does not affect the checkpoints stored on S3
      fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: 'org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.token.DynamicTemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider'

and in my Docker image for Flink i have:
RUN mkdir -p /opt/flink/plugins/flink-s3-fs-hadoop
ADD https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/1.18.1/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar /opt/flink/plugins/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/

RUN mkdir -p /opt/flink/plugins/flink-s3-fs-presto
ADD https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-s3-fs-presto/1.18.1/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.18.1.jar /opt/flink/plugins/flink-s3-fs-presto/

When i run the jobs, they fail with this error:
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to create checkpoint storage at checkpoint coordinator side.
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3a'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin(s): flink-s3-fs-hadoop. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/ for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.

Any issues with my implementation? How should Flink get set up for writing and reading from AWS S3?

Probably related
